# Double-digit example number alignment in ExPex

Tags: linguistics, expex

[image: ExPex alignment]

So I've realised that when you go from a single digit example number to a double digit one in ExPex, the text for the double digit number isn't aligned to the text for the single digit example anymore.

Is there any way to make it such that they're all aligned the same no matter what?

Comment: Please include a complete minimal working example and your question will be answered quickly, i.e. a *short* example that starts with `\documentclass{article}` and ends with `\end{document}` and demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Very lightly tested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\exnoprint}{\llap{\ep@exnoformat{\ep@rawexnoprint}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\excnt=9
\ex
\begingl
\gla L'homme est parti hier.//
\glb the.man is left yesterday.//
\glft ``The man left yesterday''//
\endgl
\xe

\ex
\begingl
\gla L'homme est parti aujourd'hui.//
\glb the.man is left today.//
\glft ``The man left today''//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]